# What is the impact of converting latin1/latin1_swedish_ci to utf8mb4/utf8mb4_unicode_ci?

Tags: mysql, collation, character-set, encoding

I was facing some issues with the character's encoding. Those are resolved by updating the CHARACTER and COLLATE for some columns in the table. So my concern is

- Is this conversion safe?
- Or can this create issues for different encoding techniques?
- Also how to convert the CHARACTER and COLLATE for multiple columns of the table in the same MySQL query?

Answer (score 0):

There are many *possible* impacts.  First, what command did you use to change the charset and collation?

The "correct" way is to

```
ALTER TABLE .. CONVERT TO ...
```

Any other change is likely to have messed up the data.  To check for that, please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM .. WHERE ..` for some non-English cell in the table.

If you have "garbage" coming out of your app, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored for further clues.

Comment: I have used ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci; to alter table

Comment: @Mehar - If you had accented letters in the table, then the data may be garbled.  (But you may not see it.)  Do that `SELECT`.

Comment: It return the same data as stored, like Jan Józef Ignacy Łukasiewicz

Comment: | Jan Józef Ignacy Łukasiewicz   | 4A616E204AC3B37A65662049676E61637920C581756B617369657769637A |
| części                         | 637AC499C59B6369                                             |

Comment: C3B3 is the correct utf8mb4 for o-acute and C581 for the L-stroke.  One more check:  `LENGTH(col)` will be 2 larger than `CHAR_LENGTH(col)` -- bytes versus characters.